# Python Unittest: Assert information sought for negative test case

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, testcase

my case is a bit more complicated. I have several tests that check for certain login procedures on routers and switches.

Setup:

```
import testcore (package that used Paramiko)
from testcore.control.ssh import SSH
import unittest
from test import support
import logging
import os
```

Here can you see one of my testcases:

```
def test_create_user_ENFORCE_2(self):

    if self.s.login():

        q=self.s.query('account')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        #self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')


        # switch to prompt account

        q=self.s.query('add 15 testuser_ENFORCE_P1 ')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        #self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        self.assertTrue('class str')
        #self.assertTrue('The Password does not comply' != '\r\n\rERROR! The Password does not comply[240 chars]ar\n')
        #self.assertIs : True('The Password does not comply', q, 'add 15 testuser_ENFORCE_P1')
        print(type(q))
        q=self.s.query('logout')
        self.s.close()
```

The test works as it should. He starts a login on the respective router / switch and executes a command on the prompt.

The problem is this:

- The test should check if I u.a. Special characters can use as a password. If so, the test is failed. The positive test would be that I can not create an account that contains special characters.

The only help after the current issue, I receive the following message on the router / switch

> 'The Password does not comply' != '\r\n\rERROR! The Password does not
>   comply[240 chars]ar\n'

How and with which assert can I do the most?

Comment: Not allowed on my test the follwowing special characters

!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~)

This should be queried by the test and accordingly, if you can not create a user can view the test as positive.

Comment: From the principle I need the correct assertion in which I can request the text or at least half the text of the return:

I hold

# self.assertTrue ('The Password does not comply'! = '\ r \ n \ rERROR! The Password does not comply [240 chars] ar \ n')
             # self.assertIs: True ('The Password does not comply', q, 'add 15 testuser_ENFORCE_P1')

For completely wrong to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, and hereby refer to the following:

```
import unittest


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_me(self):
        self.assertIn('me', 'you and me')
        self.assertIn('you', 'you and me')
        self.assertIn('and', 'you and me')
        self.assertNotIn('we', 'you and me')
        self.assertIn('we', 'you and me')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```